# Logic to use in place of Aggregate function the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am computing the frequency of values over a large table. since the result of the aggregate functions result in zero for some rows, I would like to simply skip such rows.  I could have used `NULLIF(..)` but I do not want to return a zero value. And aggregate functions aren't allowed in the `WHERE` clause. How do I refactor the my query to skip such rows?.

```
SELECT device_id,
       COUNT(*) / (MAX(signal_strength) - MIN(signal_strength)) as freq
FROMm dcu
WHERE MAX(signal_strength) - MIN(signal_strength) !=0
GROUP BY device_id

ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 4: where max(signal_strength) - min(signal_strength) !=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` for aggregate computations. For example:

```
SELECT device_id,
       COUNT(*) / (MAX(signal_strength) - MIN(signal_strength)) as freq
FROMm dcu
GROUP BY device_id
HAVING MAX(signal_strength) <> MIN(signal_strength)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the aggregate function, you cannot use `where clause` - you need to use `having clause`

```
SELECT device_id,
       COUNT(*) / (MAX(signal_strength) - MIN(signal_strength)) as freq
FROMm dcu
GROUP BY device_id
having MAX(signal_strength) - MIN(signal_strength) !=0
```